# How to resolve [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: java, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I tried to make a connection with Access but I encountered the following problem after compiling my Java file

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

my code is :

```
import java.sql.*;

public class abc
           {
            public static void main(String args[])
            {

             try 
                {
                 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                 String fn="C:/ctb/new";
                 String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver                 (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ="+fn+".accdb;";
                 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database); 
         System.out.println(conn);


                 }
            catch(Exception e)
                 {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  System.out.println("Error!");
                 }
           }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

When I copy and paste your code into Eclipse I get the error message you mention. That is because the driver name is malformed. Instead of...

```
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver                 (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ="+fn+".accdb;";
```

...you need to use...

```
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+fn+".accdb;";
```

Note the single spaces in `... Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)...`